# Return to viewpager state from a new fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I have a layout that has a viewpager. The viewpager has 2 fragments inside it. When I click on the second page I want a new fragment to pop up and fill the entire screen. I did this so far by using the following in the fragment B :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new FragmentA(),"current"); 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now when I press the back button I cant get to the previous viewpager page and cannot retain its previous state. I am thrown out of the activity on back press. 
This is my implementation of OnBackPress in the main activity:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("current");
    if(fragment != null)
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();

    if(vp.getCurrentItem() == 0)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
    vp.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

have to tried this,

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does that cal the onBackPress event?

Comment: The backpress event does work fine but i cant seem to be able to navigate back to the viewpager from the new fragment.

Comment: you have tried on click listener on back button and called onBackPress functions. it's not working?

Comment: The BackPress button is working fine and the mehtod is called too. The error lies in the implementation of the code , i think. I am still trying.